# how to show checked value from list of checkbox from database

Tags: php, html

I have a form contains check boxes named interest, I saved the checkbox value in database with comma ( e.q. cooking,reading,playing) etc. Now i want to show that checked box as checked in my form when i see the fetch the data from database.

The form is edit profile the value which is in database should already selected/checked when I see the edit profile page.

```
interest :- [checkbox1  value1]  [checkbox2 value2]  [checkbox3  value3]  [checkbox4  value4]
```

how can I do it.. please guide me..

Comment: What does your code that you have look like now? That will help point out where you are going wrong.

Comment: is this php ? Please post something related to php

Answer (score 2):

First of all, is a bad practice to store different values in a single comma separated string in a database. You should use an ´interests table´ instead.
But if you want to do it your way, you should fetch the data from the database and explode the string:

```
$interests = explode(",", $db_stored_data);
```

there you have an array with the different interests. After that, when you create the checkboxes, you should check if the interest is in this array, and depending on that you check it or not.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I html5, the attribute in the checkbox is checked="checked". But I seriously suggest you lern how to code before asking questions

Answer (score 0):

The HTML you need is

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="..." id="..." value="...">
```

`checked="checked"` is the important bit. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.checkbox.html#input.checkbox for details.